# Can I use a screw-together p-trap on a bathtub?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, p-trap

I want to install a P-trap that can be unscrewed is so I can quickly access the trap in hopes of catching anything that might fall in before it goes down to my sewer grinder and damages it. The only downside I can see is that it is a thinner pipe and that if someone was to use a drain auger that may damage it.  I do not plan on using a drain auger in that section of the plumbing.

Is there any reason I should not install a screw-together p-trap on my bathtub?

Comment: _You_ might never use an auger on the tub trap, but future you or the next owner might. Something about "the best laid plans of mice and men..."

Comment: You can find screw together P-traps made of heavier PVC.

Comment: The usual problem is "quickly access it" for a tub trap, so figure out how THAT is going to work. As already mentioned you can buy heavy PVC union traps, but you might need one or two more PVC unions (in addition) in order to actually get it apart and get something out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the drain area accessible? There's your answer. I've used compression fittings on tub drains before. The size isn't really an issue. You wouldn't want one in a fully closed-up, finished location where it could present an unnoticed leak.